# Static or relatively positioned element that respects height of position:fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I have a `position:fixed` element, with a height that differs from page to page.  Below this element, I have a `position:static` or `position:relative` element.  Is there a way to have the static/relative element respect the height of the position:fixed element?

I have a fiddle below demonstrating my conundrum:

http://jsfiddle.net/rZ7hc/2/

Comment: No - its taken out of the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow)

Comment: ...along with `position:absolute`

Comment: I have to believe there is a way around this that doesn't involve Javascript though?

Comment: This cannot be done with CSS by itself regardless of how you set the position of the element following the fixed block.  You need a JavaScript aided solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put the answer as an actual answer:

No, there is no way to have a static/relative element respect the height of the position:fixed element *without using JavaScript*.

You can do this pretty easily with something like the following jsfiddle:

```
$('#not-fixed').css('padding-top', $('#fixed').outerHeight() + 10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VYrsU/1/